# Why am I unable to launch appium inspector even if appium doctor show no issues

Tags: android, automation, appium

Have a look at my codes -

Appium inspector -

```
nfo AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
```

info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/piyushkumar
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /Users/piyushkumar/Library/Android/sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: /Users/piyushkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: /Users/piyushkumar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: /Users/piyushkumar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic completed, no fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor 
info AppiumDoctor Everything looks good, bye!
info AppiumDoctor

Appium inspector codes--

Comment: Appium shows- > MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/piyushkumar/Library/Android/sdk
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
/build-tools'
    at Error (native)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste appium logs? Sometimes appium inspector is not able to launch due to invalid app path, package name, launch/wait activity or invalid device details.